# R session is being terminated while executing comparison function using RecordLinkage ,R package

Tags: r, duplicates, fuzzy-comparison, record-linkage, bigdata

I am using RecordLinkage R package to compare two data sets of size around 100 000 approximately.

I tried that by using code

```
Rpairs<- RLBigDataLinkage(dataset1, dataset2, exclude=1, strcmpfun ="jarowinkler")
```

Below I have attached the small snap of both datasets (dataset1 and dataset2) which I am using for comparison.

[image: Dataset1]

[image: Dataset2]

While executing above code,After few minutes of execution, R session is terminating.

Things I have done:

1. I have set java parameter

   (options(java.parameters="xmx8g")
2. Have clean up disk space
3. Have executed gc()  function

As I won't get any column in datasets that matches exactly in most of the cases, I am unable to use blocking criteria.

How to solve above issue or  whether there is any other package in R that performs record linkage for large dataset similar to one I have considered?

Comment: Does it work as expected with a small sample of your data? How much memory is the R process taking? Does it abort with any errors or does R just disappear? Window, Mac or Linux? Version of everything? Please edit your question to answer the above.